# Review history pagination ignores "show skipped reviews" setting

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-history

When I browse my own [review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history?userId=42), I usually uncheck the "*show skipped reviews*" option to hide the reviews I skipped.

The problem is that this option is lost everytime I change the page, i.e. the URL flag `skipped=false` gets dropped, thus on the next page the skipped reviews are shown again.

Funny enough, if I leave the option checked, the page links have the flag `skipped=true` set.

It looks like the history page defaults to `skipped=true` but the pagination logic assumes the opposite.

Comment: Really? If I want to see skipped reviews, then I always have to click the skipped reviews button to see them. It's never on by default.

Comment: @Zizouz212 weird.. for me it's always enabled by default... Now I think that this is the actual issue here.

Comment: Is it working, broken, bug, feature, bananas... Oh the possibilities :P

Comment: For me *show skipped reviews* is always checked.  I tried what you did and it does indeed lose that it is unchecked when I click to go to a new page.  It does not reset the flag if I manually edit the page number.

Comment: I suspect that *show skipped reviews* is always checked for high rep users and unchecked for low rep users.